# How do I prevent Rails from redirecting after form submit?

Tags: forms, url, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form on the home page of my app, and it posts to the "/search" path. I want to make sure that the url path of the browser does not change after the form is submitted. Yet, I cannot redirect to home because then I would lose all the form validation stuff in the errors object.

So I'm wondering how I can submit a form without changing the url path?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to completely understand your question, sorry.

Why would you redirect users after a search and not simply GET the "/search"? Usually a POST implies you have created something in the database and now want to redirect somewhere.

Rails has "redirect_to :back" which can take you back to the same URL you came from. It's based on "request.referrer".

I suspect "redirect_to :back" should help you out but perhaps i'm lost as to why you would post to "/search" and then redirect. "/search" is not a search then? :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old question, but I had this same problem recently too and found the answer:

```
redirect_to :back
```